# How do I check if I'm connected to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Unity project for Android. I'm currently using Unity 2019.3.1 and using Firebase SDK 6.15.2. I have a function that checks for a document's existence:

```
public async void GetSpecificUserDocumentAsync(DocumentReference docRef, string onComplete)
{
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Getting document {0} from database!", onComplete));
    DocumentSnapshot task = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
    if (task.Exists)
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", task.Id));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Document does not exist!"));
    }
}
```

However, the Console keeps returning an error `FirebaseException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.` even though my computer is online.

I've went online to find a possible fix or check and found a way to check if I am online:

```
async void Func()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        GetDatabaseNode("path_to_node", SampleCallback)
    };
    //Add more tasks here...

    int timeout = 10000;
    Task timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);

    if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), timeoutTask) == timeoutTask)
    {
        // timeout logic
        Debug.Log("TIMED OUT");

    }
    else
    {
        // task completed within timeout 
    }
}
public async Task GetDatabaseNode(string path, System.Action<DocumentSnapshot> callback)
{
    await database.Collection("Data").Document("yytt").GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inner task was " + (task.IsFaulted ? "faulted." : "cancelled."));
            return;
        }

        callback?.Invoke(task.Result);
    });

    // anything that you put here will be run once the awaiting above has finished
}

private void SampleCallback(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> childSnapshot in snapshot.ToDictionary())
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("node contains: {0}", childSnapshot.Key);
    }
}
```

However, the task will always be faulted and it will immediately go to TIMEOUT. Is there a way to connect to the network when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if I'm connected to Firebase?

The Firestore SDK doesn't expose any way to determine if it thinks it's connected or not.  You have to trust that it's going to eventually retry any connections that get broken.

If you think the SDK is mistaken, and you have specific steps to reproduce the issue, file a bug report with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).